Android Google Maps Snapshot Screenshot is black
I have a problem, for some tests I'm doing I need to take a screenshot of my app that uses Google Maps. When I try to take the screenshot or snapshot, all the elements appear in the screenshot, except for where Google Maps is, which appears black.
enter image description here
I've tried to follow these other articles where I see that they mention similar errors:
<Capture screen shot of GoogleMap Android API V2 >
<Google Map Screenshot black >
This is my code for the button with screenshot:
click_screenshot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bot_screenshot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


               

                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test Snapshot Google Maps 2 X", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                            Bitmap bitmap;
                            @Override
                            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test Snapshot Google Maps 2 Y", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                bitmap = snapshot;
                                try {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test Snapshot Google Maps 2 Z", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Bitmap screenshot = capturescreenshot(linearLayout1);
                                    imageView_scre.setImageBitmap(screenshot);
                                    storeimageasjpeg(screenshot);

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }/**/
                               

                            }
                        };

                        googleMap.snapshot(callback); //si funciona


                    }
                });


 public Bitmap capturescreenshot(View view){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "capturescreenshot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bitmap returnBitnap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnBitnap);
        Drawable bgdrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgdrawable != null){
            bgdrawable.draw(canvas);
        }
        else {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnBitnap;
    }

    public void storeimageasjpeg(Bitmap bitmap){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "storeimageasjpeg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        OutputStream outst;
        try {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
                    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,"Image_"+".jpg");
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpeg");
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+File.separator+"TestFolder");
                    Uri imageUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

                    outst = contentResolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outst);
                    Objects.requireNonNull(outst);

                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image is saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Could you tell me what I can do to correct it and make it visible?

Delete the capturescreenshot() method.
Then, replace:
                        GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                            Bitmap bitmap;
                            @Override
                            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test Snapshot Google Maps 2 Y", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                bitmap = snapshot;
                                try {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test Snapshot Google Maps 2 Z", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Bitmap screenshot = capturescreenshot(linearLayout1);
                                    imageView_scre.setImageBitmap(screenshot);
                                    storeimageasjpeg(screenshot);

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }/**/
                               

                            }
                        };

with:
                        GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                                try {
                                    imageView_scre.setImageBitmap(snapshot);
                                    storeimageasjpeg(snapshot);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        };

The snapshot image passed to onSnapshotReady() is your image. This is covered in the answers to one of the questions that you linked to.

I have another implementation that is much simpler. The reason when we capture the screen is that we cannot capture the image of MapView because MapView uses sufaceView (this type of view is different from normal views).
Idea

Create an ImageView with size = MapView (but set GONE)
when clicking to take a photo -> getBitmap from MapView -> set to ImageView (and set Visible and GONE MapView at the same time)
take a photo
after taking a photo -> Gone ImageView and Visible MapView at the same time

First. create an ImageView with the same size as your MapView,
I use MapView, if you have other types like SupportMapFragment, the way to do it is similar.
      <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dp10"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/dp25"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="@dimen/dp70"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="@dimen/dp5" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

Then:
googleMap.snapshot(bitmap -> {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        showImageMapWithMapSnapshot(bitmap);
    }
    capturescreenshot(cardView)
});

showImageMapWithMapSnapshot()
used to setBitmap and set to Image, then GONE MapView
private void showImageMapWithMapSnapshot(Bitmap bitmap) {
    viewBinding.mapView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewBinding.imageMap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    viewBinding.imageMap.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

Important. You need to GONE ImageView, and make MapView visible again after taking screenshot using this function
private void hideImageMapAndShowMap() {
    viewBinding.mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    viewBinding.imageMap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

